# Booting straight into a game to skip the OS and open up a ton of resources?

Tags: boot, bootloader, gaming, steam

So like if I have an extra computer laying around, I can basically turn it into an arcade machine, and have it run games a lot better than it should because of it. This is Steam games in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back in the day, with *extremely* limited resources, and mostly standard systems, it was possible. You knew you had a 8086 processor, a fairly standard set of video outputs

Many games would boot *directly* off a disk. With modern machines the benefits are limited to say the least - especially when you're talking about steam.

Nowadays, the hardware stack, right down to the processor needs drivers for full functionality. A bootable game would need a *fairly* comprehensive kernel, drivers... etc.

Since most arbitrary games run on windows or linux, to run such games, your hypothetical kernel would need to support the APIs these games support. OpenGL is fairly common, and if you had a video driver that supports it, porting is plausible. DirectX is trickier.

At the end of the day your directly bootable game would have a good chunk of a proper, common OS running underneath it.

Amusingly, modern consoles are often x86 or at least general purpose systems (running variants of powerpc, or I guess ARM or MIPS), they do run cut-down, specialized versions of standard OSes - Sony uses Freebsd, MS uses a Windows varient and so on.

So, practically speaking, there's no modern system I know of that does what you want. You need an underlying OS to run Steam (linux or windows) - and even steamos is debian running steam as its main UI. You'd need to roll in/write basically an entire OS (a non trivial task!) and drivers to get everything to work.

In theory, you *could* start off an extremely minimal install of windows or linux, carefully pare down the system for the drivers you need, streamline the boot process and so on. [Steamos](http://store.steampowered.com/steamos/) is an example of that. You could also find tools to remaster a windows install to be more minimal, though with modern systems, I suspect the time spent would be considerable, and the utility minimal.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind to get even remotely close to what is wanted would be [SteamOS](http://store.steampowered.com/steamos/) , but as far as that, I agree with you, I don't see any way to do this otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "boot" into a game. Games are just programs running on an operating system, and usually require "tons of resources". That being said, for Steam there is the option of SteamOS: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SteamOS

> SteamOS is a Debian-based Linux operating system by Valve Corporation and is the primary operating system for Valve's Steam Machine video game console. It was released alongside the start of end-user beta testing of Steam Machines in December 2013.

Comment: While I agree Journeyman Geek's answer is much better (I actually upvoted it) can I get an explanation for the downvote? Just want to improve my answers in the future!

Comment: User wants to not load an operating system, and your answer to his question, is to use an operating system to launch a game. While Journeyman did mention SteamOS, the key factoid in their answer is basically that's an unrealistic expectation

Comment: I don't really get your point...Aren't we both saying that not using an operating system is not possible? Journeyman's answer is of course much more detailed, but we are essentially saying the same thing?

Comment: Alright; We will have to agree to disagree I guess;

Comment: Understood. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: I don't see why you got a down vote, your answer I think was perfectly acceptable saying that this was not possible and here is an option. Even though Journeyman's was a great answer. You still provided the simplified answer to the question. I would personally go with SteamOS just to minimize resources, as this is was it was designed to do. Take my Upvote to help.